# Training a neural network without collapsing

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, dataloader

I am trying to train a pytorch neural network to map from image space to 2D. I have the condition that I only want to use the ReLU activation function, linear layers, conv2d layers, and avgpool2d layers. I have created my dataset by taking a single (32,32,3) image and rotating it by angle values defined by: angle_degrees = np.linspace(0, 360, 24841). Performing PCA on this dataset renders a nice circle in 2D as expected but I am unable to train a neural network to give me a similar result.

I have trained several neural networks and all of them are such that all of my training data get mapped to the same 2D point. Can anyone provide an example of a neural net that maps rotated images to a circle without this collapsing problem?

I have tried many things, but my most recent attempt was with a linear model:

(data_path is the path to where I have 224x224x3 images saved and I create a dataset by choosing the first of these images [here is the 224x224x3 image I personally used from the MIRO dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSwYm.png) and rotating it)

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
from tqdm import tqdm as tqdm_regular
import seaborn as sns
import random
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.datasets as Datasets
from torchvision.utils import make_grid
import jupyter
import ipywidgets
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
#from PIL import Images
import PIL.Image as Image
from skimage.transform import downscale_local_mean
from torchvision.datasets.vision import VisionDataset
import os
from intvalpy import lineqs
import numpy as np
import cvxpy
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from typing import Any, Callable, Optional, Tuple

#  configuring device
if torch.cuda.is_available():
  device = torch.device('cuda:0')
  print('Running on the GPU')
else:
  device = torch.device('cpu')
  print('Running on the CPU')

# -------------------------
# Create the rotated images
# -------------------------
first_image_name = os.listdir(data_path)[0]
image_path = data_path + first_image_name
image = Image.open(image_path)

# convert the image to a NumPy array
image_array = np.array(image)

# define the rotations for the new sequence of images
angle_degrees = np.linspace(0, 360, 360*69+1)

for angle in angle_degrees:
    # rotate the image array by the specified angle
    rotated_image_array = rotate(image_array, angle=angle, reshape=False, cval=255)

    # convert the array to an image
    rotated_image = Image.fromarray(rotated_image_array)

    # downscale the image   reference:https://scikit image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/transform/plot_rescale.html
    red_channel = rotated_image_array[:, :, 0]
    green_channel = rotated_image_array[:, :, 1]
    blue_channel = rotated_image_array[:, :, 2]
    scale_factor = int(224 / 32)  # original_size/target_size
    downscaled_red_channel = downscale_local_mean(red_channel, (scale_factor, scale_factor))
    downscaled_green_channel = downscale_local_mean(green_channel, (scale_factor, scale_factor))
    downscaled_blue_channel = downscale_local_mean(blue_channel, (scale_factor, scale_factor))
    downscaled_image_array = np.stack((downscaled_red_channel,
                                       downscaled_green_channel,
                                       downscaled_blue_channel), axis=-1)

    # convert the array to an image
    rotated_image = Image.fromarray(downscaled_image_array.astype(np.uint8))

    # save the low-resolution image
    rotated_image.save(save_path + 'image_' + '{:07.3f}'.format(angle) + '.png')

# -----------------------------------
# Define the datasets from the images 
# -----------------------------------
# I use https://blog.paperspace.com/convolutional-autoencoder/ as a template 

class RotatedCarDataset(VisionDataset): # this replaces the Datasets.CIFAR10 class
    def __init__(self,
                 root: str,
                 transform: Optional[Callable] = None,
                 target_transform: Optional[Callable] = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(root, transform=transform, target_transform=target_transform)
        angles = np.linspace(0, 360, 360 * 69 + 1)  # Angle values
        self.data: Any = []
        self.targets: Any = []

        images_as_arrays = []
        for angle in angles:
            img_float = '{:07.3f}'.format(angle)
            image_path = os.path.join(self.root, f'image_{img_float}.png')  # f'image_{angle_str}.png')
            image = Image.open(image_path)
            image_array = np.array(image)
            self.data.append(image_array)

        self.data = np.vstack(self.data).reshape(-1, 32, 32, 3) # convert to HWC

        # get targets from data by performing PCA
        flattened_images = [image.reshape(-1) for image in self.data]
        X = np.stack(flattened_images, axis=0)
        x_bar = (np.sum(X, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1))*(1/X.shape[1]) #get the data's mean
        X_tilde = X-x_bar #center data around 0
        n_components = 2  # Number of dimensions to reduce to
        pca = PCA(n_components=n_components)
        X_2d = pca.fit_transform(X_tilde)

        #normalize targets
        desired_mean = 0.5
        desired_std = 0.5
        # Step 1: Calculate the current mean and standard deviation of the matrix
        current_mean = np.mean(X_2d)
        current_std = np.std(X_2d)
        # Step 2: Calculate scaling factors
        mean_scaling_factor = (desired_mean - current_mean)
        std_scaling_factor = desired_std / current_std
        # Step 3: Normalize the matrix
        normalized_matrix = (X_2d + mean_scaling_factor) * std_scaling_factor
        self.targets = normalized_matrix

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img, target = self.data[index], self.targets[index]

        img = Image.fromarray(img)

        if self.transform is not None:
          img = self.transform(img)

        if self.target_transform is not None:
          target = self.target_transform(target)

        return img, target  

training_set = RotatedCarDataset(root=save_path,
                                 transform=transforms.ToTensor())
validation_set = RotatedCarDataset(root=save_path,
                                   transform=transforms.ToTensor())



class CustomRotatedCarDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset, transforms=None, target_transforms=None):
        self.data = dataset.data
        self.targets = dataset.targets
        self.transforms = transforms
        self.target_transforms = target_transforms

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image = self.data[idx]
        label = self.targets[idx]

        if self.transforms != None:
            image = self.transforms(image)
        if self.target_transforms != None:
            label = self.target_transforms(label)
        return image, label


#  creating pytorch datasets
training_data = CustomRotatedCarDataset(training_set,
                                        transforms=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                                   transforms.Normalize((0.5,0.5,0.5),(0.5, 0.5,0.5))]))


validation_data = CustomRotatedCarDataset(validation_set,
                                          transforms=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                                                         transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5),(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))]))


# Define the model

class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_sizes, num_classes):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_sizes = hidden_sizes

        # Create layers dynamically based on the hidden_sizes list
        for i in range(len(hidden_sizes)):
            layer_name = f"l{i + 1}"
            relu_name = f"relu{i + 1}"
            if i == 0:

                setattr(self, layer_name, nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_sizes[i]))
                setattr(self, relu_name, nn.ReLU())
            else:
                setattr(self, layer_name, nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[i - 1], hidden_sizes[i]))
                setattr(self, relu_name, nn.ReLU())

        output_layer_name = f"l{len(hidden_sizes) + 1}"

        setattr(self, output_layer_name, nn.Linear(hidden_sizes[-1], num_classes))

    def forward(self, x):
        out = x
        for i in range(len(self.hidden_sizes)):
            layer_name = f"l{i + 1}"
            relu_name = f"relu{i + 1}"
            out = getattr(self, layer_name)(out)
            out = getattr(self, relu_name)(out)

        output_layer_name = f"l{len(self.hidden_sizes) + 1}"
        out = getattr(self, output_layer_name)(out)

        return out


#model = NeuralNet(input_size=2, num_classes=1, hidden_sizes=[10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
model = NeuralNet(input_size=3072, num_classes=2, hidden_sizes=[1000, 1000, 1000, 1000]) #hidden_sizes=[10, 10, 10, 10])
model.eval()

#--------------------+
# Train the model |
#--------------------+

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

#epochs = 2000
epochs = 20
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = model.to(device)
model.type(torch.float32)
train_loader = DataLoader(training_data, 64)

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):

    # train step
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    #for batch_idx, data in enumerate(dataloader, 1):
    for batch_idx, dataset in enumerate(train_loader, 1):
        # prep data
        #data, target = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1:]
        data, target = dataset[0], dataset[1]
        data = data.reshape(-1, 3072)
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()  # zero accumulated gradients
        output = model(data)
        #print('output = ', output)

        # calculate loss and perform backprop
        loss = criterion(output, target.type(torch.float32))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item()

    # print('    total loss ', total_loss)

    # model.cuda()
    model.to(device)
    model.train()
    model.type(torch.float32)
    # print loss stats
    print("Epoch: {}, Loss: {}".format(epoch, total_loss / len(train_loader)))
```

Comment: So essentially you want to train an autoencoder such that it's latent space will look like the output of PCA?

Comment: @YakovDan It does not necessarily need to be an autoencoder; I want any neural network with the limitation that it only has linear, conv2d, avgpool2d, and batchnorm2d layers and uses the ReLU activation function. I used https://blog.paperspace.com/convolutional-autoencoder/ as a template to create my datasets. But yes, I want the output of the neural network (or the 2D bottleneck if using an autoencoder) to look like the output of PCA for my training data (which in my example should be a circle).

Comment: Got it. Can you provide an input image as an example?

Comment: I have just added the image I used in my post. Please let me know if there is a better way for me to provide the image.

Comment: I think the training dataset was too big for a model of the type and size that I defined to fit it all. I just redefined my data using angles = np.linspace(0, 360, 361) and I am getting the desired representation as the output.